# Geographical landing pages not showing up on Google search results

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, search-results

**Problem we have: One markets' geographical landing pages do not appear on search results.**

Few months ago we discovered that robots.txt are blocking Google from indexing that markets' pages. We fixed it. Resubmitted the sitemap to Search Console.

Few months have passed but:
1. Search Console is not showing any results for the geo landing pages (last 90 days).
2. Google Analytics shows only few (11) pageviews in the past 2 months.

We cannot figure out where to look next.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Kristina